# Simple Injector - Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor on production

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am stuck with a strange situation. I am following `Onion Architecture` and my architecture is something like this:

```
1-Core
     - Domain Classes
     - Repository Interfaces
     - Service Interfaces
2-Infrastructure
     - Data
     - Dependency Injection // Here I am using Simple Injector as dependency injection
     - Repository Interfaces Implementation
     - Service Interfaces Implementation
3-WebApi
     - Web Api Project
4-WebClient
     - My AngularJs App
5-Test
     - Test Project
```

**Dependency Injection:**

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(IocConfig), "RegisterDependencies")]
namespace Infrastructure.DependencyResolution
{
    public class IocConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterDependencies()
        {
            var container = new Container();

            container.RegisterWebApiRequest<IRepositoryAsync<Category>, Repository<Category>>();
            container.RegisterWebApiRequest<ICategoryService, CategoryService>();
            container.RegisterWebApiRequest<IDataContextAsync>(() => new MyContext());
            container.Verify();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
            new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        }
    }
}
```

**Web Api Project:**

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ICategoryService _categoryService;
    public HomeController(ICategoryService categoryService)
    {
        _categoryService = categoryService;
    }
}
```

Everything is working very fine on my `local IIS`. But now I have published this application to the production server and now it is giving me below error:

> {"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"An error
>   occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'HomeController'.
>   Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public
>   constructor.","exceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","stackTrace":"
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage
>   request)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()","innerException":{"message":"An
>   error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Type
>   'JetAdz.WebApi.Controllers.HomeController' does not have a default
>   constructor","exceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","stackTrace":"
>   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type
>   instanceType)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)"}}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please take a look at the inner exception of the thrown exception. It contains the details that describes why this is happening.

There are multiple problems here. You should make sure that you *register all your root types explicitly* in the container. Controllers are root types, because they are resolved directly (nothing depends on them, but they have dependencies). If you don't register them explicitly, the container is unable to check if they can be created when you call `Verify()`. You can register your controllers by calling the following:

```
container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

This is described in [the documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/webapiintegration.html).

After doing this, you probably directly see the `Verify()` method fail when you start the application, and in this case you get a very detailed message explaining what is going wrong.

From the inner exception you can see that Web API's `DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator` method is calling `TypeActivator.Create<T>(Type)`. This only happens when the call to `request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(controllerType)` returns `null`. But this is typically something that can't happen if you hooked in the `SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver` into the Web API pipeline. This is because the `SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver` will never return `null` when it is requested to resolve an `IHttpController` implementation. Instead it will throw an exception when a controller can't be resolved.

So this to me is an indication of a binding redirect problem in your application. This means that the SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi.dll is referring to a different `IHttpController` version than what your application is using. Binding redirects are meant to solve this, so make sure that your application has the correct binding. For the System.Web.Http.dll it looks like this (but note that you might need other bindings as well):

```xml
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    ... 
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" 
          culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Usually the bindings are managed by NuGet package manager, but it fails to do so on a regular basis.

When the binding redirect issue is fixed, you'll see that the inner exception contains information that comes from Simple Injector with the same information you'll see when calling `Verify()`.

Comment: How can I see inner exception on production server?

Comment: Contact you system administrator. He know how to get this information.

Comment: Ok I got the inner exception and it is like that: "innerException":{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Type 'JetAdz.WebApi.Controllers.HomeController' does not have a default constructor","exceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","stackTrace":" at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)

Comment: @UsmanKhalid: Please update your question and add the full exception details.

Answer (score 8):

You are not registering the correct DependencyResolver for WebApi. According to the [WebApi Dependency Injection page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection) and the [Simple Injector WebApi page](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/webapiintegration.html), it is supposed to be done like this.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var container = new Container();

    container.RegisterWebApiRequest<IRepositoryAsync<Category>, Repository<Category>>();
    container.RegisterWebApiRequest<ICategoryService, CategoryService>();
    container.RegisterWebApiRequest<IDataContextAsync>(() => new MyContext());
    container.Verify();

    config.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    // Other Web API configuration not shown.
}
```

The configuration you have shown is for MVC dependency injection (which you may also need).

Comment: This seems interesting but then why it is running perfectly on my local iis.

Comment: Probably because it is running in classic mode.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and time.Few lines of this code directed me to right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I use spring XML files to inject variables into my classes.  In my case it was a copy/paste bug when I created a new controller.

So while this isn't exactly related to the OP problem it gets the same error message and my help someone else.

I had copied (angle brackets changed to square brackets):

```
[object id="className" type="Project.ClassName" scope="request"]
    [constructor-arg name="OtherClassName" ref="otherclassName"/]
[/object]
```

when what I needed was:

```
[object id="className" type="Project.ClassName" scope="request"]
    [property name="OtherClassName" ref="otherclassName"/]
[/object]
```

Note the **property** instead of **constructor-arg**.

Because my class didn't have a constructor looking for a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was simply that I had forgotten to add `SimpleInjectorInitializer.Initialize();` to my `Application_Start()`.

I typically create a `SimpleInjectorInitializer` class in the `App_Start` folder these days, within which I do the `container.Verify()` and `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);` calls; after I've called my `GetInitializeContainer()` method that's doing all the type registrations, etc.